# Google Cloud Workflow - Fetch Bearer Token Step

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workflows

In my use case I want to create a step in Google Cloud Workflow where I can pass my username and password and return the resultant bearer token in a variable. Was wondering how the yaml config for such a workflow would look like ?

My endpoint expects a request in the following manner :

POST 'https://cloud.business.io/v2/login' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
--data-urlencode 'username=business@xyz.io' 
--data-urlencode 'password=APassword123'

Answer (score 4):

Found it with a little trial and error !

```
call: http.post
args:
    url: https://cloud.business.io/v2/login
    headers:
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    body :
        'username': 'business@xyz.io'
        'password': 'APassword123'
result: BearerToken
```

Comment: Thanks for this, you saved me a lot of digging around. Google's docs could do with a little polish, around workflow modules like 'http' and scenarios.